# I'm having trouble solving this PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The original equation is $$u_{xx}-u_{yy}+2u_x+2u_y=0$$ What I did is change variables $$v=x-y,w=x+y$$ This way I get $4u_{vw}+4u_w=0$.

However, if I do instead $$\partial_x+\partial_y=\partial_v , \partial_x-\partial_y=\partial_w$$ I get the equation $u_{vw}+2u_v=0$.

Is this the same result? How do I get to the final expression of u?

Comment: Consider the new differential equation as a first-order PDE for $u_v$ (or $u_w$ depending which of the two you use). You must have made an error somewhere since your transformations in either case are the same but with $u,v$ swapped.

Comment: Only one of them can be right. I'm sure you can redo your workings and check which is right. You should get the same equation in both cases.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm asking.. after repeating quite some times I keep on getting the same thing.

Comment: Show your workings and I'll tell you where the mistake is. The first looks right to me

Comment: The second is that $u_{xx}-u_{yy}=u_{vw}$ by multiplying and $u_x=\frac 12 (u_v+u_w), u_y=\frac 12 (u_v-u_w)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method is correct, giving the p.d.e.
$$u_{vw} + u_w = 0 .$$

**Hint** In the new variable $r := u_w$, the p.d.e. is
$$r_v + r = 0 .$$

> The p.d.e. in $r$ has solutions $$u_w = r = f(w) e^{-v}$$ for differentiable $f$, and integrating again gives $$u(v, w) = F(w) e^{-v} + G(v) .$$ for twice-differentiable $F, G$. In terms of $x, y$, $$\boxed{u(x, y) = F(x + y) e^{-(x - y)} + G(x - y)} .$$

Comment: But what is wrong with the second method? A bit more details are in the comments.

Comment: Why is $v,w$ swapped in the final answer?

Comment: Your formulae for converting from $\partial_x, \partial_y$ to $\partial_v, \partial_w$ appear incorrect. To answer your second question, the switch was just a transcription error. I've fixed the issue.